# VSCode Expo Debugging Instance does not connect to packager correctly

Tags: expo, vscode-debugger

I am attempting to attach a VSCode Debugging instance to the packager of my Expo virtual Android Device. When Expo is started, on port 19000 (`Metro waiting on exp://192.168.1.119:19000`), with the correct port set in both the `launch.JSON` and the `settings.JSON`, the run and debug tab does not display any variables, or stop at set breakpoints.

```
{
      "name": "Attach to packager",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "type": "reactnative",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 19000
    }
```

```
"react-native.packager.port": 19000,
```

[image]

I understand this has been covered in other questions, but many of those have been solved by pressing/using the *Remote JS Debugging* button in the Expo app on the VM, although it seems this doesnt exist anymore, and has been replaced by a *Open JS Debugger* button. Pressing this does not solve my problem.

Any suggestions on getting it to correctly attach? I am only new to Expo/React-Native so could be stupid. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I kinda forgot it said that in the text haha. Sorry everybody, could've been worse I suppose.

Comment: said _what_ in the text?

Comment: @user in the view body; it's irrelevant to the question.